# Rails 400 and 500 error page in development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to display the 500 error page whenever exception occurs. below is my setting

in development.rb file

```
                   config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
```

and also override the method local_request in application_controller.rb file

```
         def local_request?
               false
          end
```

But still  not able to display 500 page on local machine in case of exception. I also tried to run app on production mode, but still getting same result.However i can successfully display 500 web page using IP address.plz help

Answer (score 0):

Are you routing them properly?  You can do custom error pages by putting in your application.rb:

```
# For error handling
config.exceptions_app = self.routes
```

Then in your routes.rb file:

```
## Routes for Exceptions
match '/404', to: "static#not_found",       as: "not_found"
match '/422', to: "static#rejected",        as: "rejected"
match '/500', to: "static#something_wrong", as: "something_wrong"
```

Assuming you have a "static" controller (use whatever you want).  Then render out the templates as you normally would.